# Angular $location.path is not working

Tags: angularjs

i am using angular with web api problem is when i use
 $location.url("/home");
home page did not display when i checked user url (in chrome development toll)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$compile/tpload?p0=template%2Fhome.html&p1=undefined&p2=undefined

in url template%2Fhome.html where as my path template/home so what is %2F

kindly help me
regards,
Akmal.

Comment: %2F is the url-encoded `/` character. The problem is that your template can't be loaded from the URL you gave.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using version 1.4 it won't be a problem. But if you're using 1.5 and up you must supply this in your config:

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if the other options don't work:

```
$timeout(function () {
    $location.path('/home');
});
```

Don't forget to inject `$timeout`

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the `$routeParams` service injected in your js file along with `$location`?